# JQuery - Parsing xml text node stops at colon

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, special-characters

I am parsing an xml file with jquery and ajax. I noticed that it doesn't output the proceeding characters after a ':' in the text node. I tried using &59; and escaping it (\:) but it doesn't my solve problem.

e.g.

```
<some>
      <text>dssadsa dasdasd : dsadasdaasdsadas</text>
</some>
```

$(this).children('text').text() will just display dssadsa dasdasd :

I know this is trivial but I can't really solve it. Thanks

edit...
hahaha my bad. I am injecting it to the value attribute of  tag. yeah it shows in alert completely. but how to do it in a input textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `\\:`   (i.e. double back slash to escape colon)

**Edit**: (after viewing the complete problem)

Put double quotes in `value` attribute.

http://jsbin.com/oxafef/edit#javascript,html

Comment: it didn't solved it. i am trying to put it as a value for <input type="text"> tag, not simply as a text. sorry for not giving a detailed description of the problem

Comment: @Jinnean

Put doulbe quotes in value attribute.

http://jsbin.com/oxafef/edit#javascript,html

Comment: i knew it! yeah, there's no double quotes there. Thanks Jashwant.

Comment: ok, i thought what i just have to do is upvote the comment since the answer was in the comment